# VS 2022 "Unable to connect to web server 'IIS Express'"

Tags: c#, .net, iis, iis-express

Hello I want to apply Hsts (Strict-Transport-Security) and I want to implement and test in my local.
But i can't change my application Url from http to https version . I tried solutions  on other answers but did not worked. I tried 443 port / I tried delete .vs config file but it does not exist.

```
{
      "iisSettings": {
        "windowsAuthentication": false,
        "anonymousAuthentication": true,
        "iisExpress": {
          "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:47000",// This was working http 
          "sslPort": 0
        }
      },
      "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
      "profiles": {
        "IIS Express": {
          "commandName": "IISExpress",
          "launchBrowser": true,
          "launchUrl": "swagger/index.html",
          "environmentVariables": {
            "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
          }
        },
        "Product.Core.WebApi": {
          "commandName": "Project",
          "launchBrowser": true,
          "launchUrl": "api/values",
          "environmentVariables": {
            "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
          },
          "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5000"
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Your changes to IIS Express/VS/project settings are not in sync, so IIS Express cannot be launched. Don't waste your time here if you really want to test things like HSTS. Instead, hosting your web app on local IIS, and use VS IIS integration to debug it, because IIS can hook to port 443 freely.

Comment: Thank you I'm going to try use IIS locally @LexLi

Comment: Lex's comment is useful, I also want to share you [the official](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-enable-debugging-for-aspnet-applications?view=vs-2022).